# Login in camunda cockpit AKS Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, camunda, sticky-session, cockpit

I learn from you that the solution is enabling sticky-sessions using cookies to ingress controller (K8s nginx). This would ensure that all requests from a given user are directed to the same instance over a configurable period of time.

It's a good solution and resolve the login cookpit.

But i've a important question:

into my architecture there are:

1 microservices camunda with 2 POD
Others microservices that call api rest camunda fecthAndLock.
if i enable sticky-sessions, lose the benefit of scaling pod? All requests from a microservice A to Camunda user are directed to the same POD?

[image]